# How do you punctuate phone numbers in Japanese?

Tags: orthography, numbers, punctuation

Given the phone number in English:

> (012) 345-6789

how do you write this in Japanese?  Is it:

> （０１２）３４５－６７８９

or:

> ０１２・３４５・６７８９

or somewhere in between?  My personal research suggests the first one is the right way to do it, but I'm suspicious.  Thanks!

Comment: googling Japanese business cards doesn't show ０１２・３４５・６７８９ at all. （０１２）３４５－６７８９ was more common and some cases had it as ０１ ２３４５ ６７８９

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my (and others') Japanese business cards, we use spaces or dashes, never dots. International formatting is appropriate, even if you don't expect to give your card outside of Japan. So these are all appropriate:

- 03 XXXX YYYY
- 08-XXXX-YYYY
- 080 XXXX YYYY
- 080-XXXX-YYYY
- +81 3 XXXX YYYY
- +81 90 XXXX YYYY

Out of my many business cards, I have none that use parentheses for the area code. A couple of times I've seen parentheses used for a small edge case of international dialing, like so:

- +81 (0)80 XXXX YYYY

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen dots been used during my entire life; dashes are used.

Comment: Should it be (012) 345-6789 or 012-345-6789?

Comment: Parenthesis are used to indicate that you can omit that part under some situations (like calling from within the city). So if it's the city code, you can use parenthesis (but using dashes all the way is ok, too)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that phone numbers, like addresses, should be written in the format of the country where they reside.

Periods (not middle dots) are used by a few countries, e.g. Belgium: `012/34.56.78`.

If it's a UK phone number, `(0123) 456-7890` seems to be the common format.

If it's a Japanese number, then `(012) 3456-7890` works (except for the "free dial" numbers, which use format of `0120-345-678` or `(0120)-345678`).

If you're putting the number down on a business card which you may give out in different countries, then the most appropriate is probably the international format: `+81 12 3456 7890` or `+44 123 456 7890`.